# Is there any way to allow a low-reputation user to chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I think that [Ping device connected to host having LAN access](https://serverfault.com/questions/1113351/ping-device-connected-to-host-having-lan-access) is probably a very simple problem, but the OP is  new to SF and isn't always providing the right information in a useful fashion. I think we're probably well beyond the point that comments are useful. I had hoped to engage the OP in chat, but because they are a new user with a 1 reputation they were unable to participate.

I understand the reason for that limitation, but I wish it were possible for them to participate in a chat *by invitation* from another user with sufficiently high reputation.

Are there any mechanisms available right now that would allow a new user to participate in chat?

Comment: It just takes 2 upvotes to get someone to the 20 rep they need to chat (I think that's the threshold).  You obviously think it's a worthwhile question, so you could cast the first vote...